# Convert varchar int time format SQL

Tags: sql, database

I want to write query that basically results in appointment time . Here is whole picture I want . [image]

Problem is that Time column in FL_CO_APPOINTMENT table is varchar(50) and in desired column Appointment format is 09:00 - 11:00 01/12/2012  . How can I manipulate Time column which is varchar(50) to get result as mentioned from desired formula. I have google but didnt find any help. Thank you.

Comment: IMHO that's far from perfect db schema design. Is it a possibility to change schema to have normal `datetime` columns (e.g. `app_start` and `app_end`)? If yes then you'll be equipped with all date and time functions.

Comment: Nope i can't change design. But I can suggest to my seniors in office. Thank you.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the varchar field to datetime.

try this

```
select  '('+Convert(varchar,convert(datetime,'09:00 AM'),108) + ' - ' +Convert(varchar, dateadd(minute,10,convert(datetime,'09:00 AM')),108) +') '+ Convert(varchar,convert(datetime,'2013-02-04 00:00:00.000'),101)
```

As per you table

```
select  '('+Convert(varchar,convert(datetime,[Time]),108) + ' - ' +Convert(varchar, dateadd(minute,[DURATION],convert(datetime,[TIME])),108) +') '+ Convert(varchar,convert(datetime,[AppointmentDate]),101)
from FL_CO_APPOINTMENT JOIN FL_FAULT ON ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I consult to senior they suggest me this solution.
  `substring(CONVERT(varchar,convert(datetime,FL_CO_APPOINTMENT.AppointmentDate)+FL_CO_APPOINTMENT.Time),13,5) +'' - ''+ substring(convert(varchar,DATEADD(HOUR,2,convert(datetime,FL_CO_APPOINTMENT.AppointmentDate)+FL_CO_APPOINTMENT.Time)),13,5) +''  ''+ convert(varchar, FL_CO_APPOINTMENT.AppointmentDate, 11) Appointment`

Thank you everyone for your answers